# Upgrade blocked in SP2013 Enterprise Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, update, service-pack

I have a SharePoint farm with two WFE servers, two backend servers and two SQL servers. I last installed CU's last year (July 2017).

I have gone to the servers in the farm this week to see that upgrades are required, but that the two WFE servers are blocked because the two backend servers are claiming that they require SP1 to be installed:

> Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB3213569)
>   64-Bit Edition 15.0.4945.1000 Missing/Required
>
> Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2880552) 64-Bit
>   Edition 15.0.4571.1502 Missing/Required

The thing is, I already installed SP1 in 2014 (I mean, I must have installed it, because you can't install any subsequent CU's with out it!)

My questions are:

1. Why is it asking for something that's already been installed?
2. Can I just reinstall SP1? What will happen if I reinstall it?
3. If I can't, what are my options?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Why is it asking for something that's already been installed?**

Looks like you didn't run the configuration wizard on all sharepoint server cross the farm after installing the patch read more at [Find Farm Patch Level / latest Cumulative Update](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)

**Can I just reinstall SP1? What will happen if I reinstall it?**

You can’t rollback the Cumulative Update Installation. So it's highly recommended to perform a full backup before starting the update process.

**If I can't, what are my options?**

- Perform a full backup.
- Make sure that SP 1 is installed on all SharePoint Server cross the farm.
- Run the configuration wizard on all SharePoint Server cross the farm (it requires downtime)

Check Also [Health Analyzer Issue: Product/patch installation or server upgrade required.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/11/21/product-patch-installation-or-server-upgrade-required/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have checked under the "Installed Updates" (in Control Panel), and can confirm that SP1 was definitely installed (as were the July 2017 CU packages). Should I just run the PSCofig GUI, or PowerShell? If so, what options/parameters should I be aware of?

Comment: FWIW, I certainly ran the Config Wizard after the July 2017 CU. I can only hope that running it again sorts the issue.

Comment: Do I run the Config Wizrd GUI? Or the Powershell?

Which options should I select (or just leave the default/pre-completed options)?

Comment: doesn't matter, if it fails with GUI , run this one PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures

Answer (score 0):

It is quite strange that it happened like that. As you say you have already installed later CUs.

Sometimes after the installation the farm info is not refreshed and you cannot run the PSConfig.

Try running this command and then run the PSConfig.

```
add-pssnapin *sharepoint*
Get-SPProduct -local
```

After that execute PSConfig either GUI or this command:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install
```